# Throttle friction lock - what is it?

Tags: general-aviation

Referring to a general aviation airplane, what is the throttle friction lock and what do I need it for?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's a device that makes the throttle harder to move. You need it to keep the engine vibrations from slowly moving the throttle away from where you left it during cruise.